# Using Xuggler for MXF to FLV

Tags: java, xuggler

I am trying to transcode an mxf file to flv type using Xuggler.

But I am getting this exception -

```
2011-09-23 11:48:06,328 [main] WARN  com.xuggle.xuggler - Got error: picture is not of the same PixelType as this Coder expected (../../../../../../../csrc/com/xuggle/xuggler/StreamCoder.cpp:1204)
```

My code is very simple and it looks like this -

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    // create a media reader
    IMediaReader mediaReader = ToolFactory.makeReader(inputFilename);

    // create a media writer
    IMediaWriter mediaWriter = ToolFactory.makeWriter(outputFilename,
            mediaReader);

    // add a writer to the reader, to create the output file
    mediaReader.addListener(mediaWriter);

    // create a media viewer with stats enabled
    // IMediaViewer mediaViewer = ToolFactory.makeViewer(true);

    // add a viewer to the reader, to see the decoded media
    // mediaReader.addListener(mediaViewer);

    // read and decode packets from the source file and
    // and dispatch decoded audio and video to the writer
    while (mediaReader.readPacket() == null)
        ;

}
```

It works for files like MP4 and MOV types.

Any pointers please.

Since no one replied and I could not find any solution, I decided to do using command arguments from Java.

I tried this and I am getting errors -

```
public class FfmpegCommandTest {

public static void main(String args[]) {

    String commandStr[] = { "ffmpeg -f dv -i \"C:\temp\0001NY.MXF\" -ar 44100 -v codec libx264 -maxrate 2000k -bufsize 2000k -vf scale=\"iw/2:ih/2\" -strict experimental -vstats_file \"C:\nasir\progress.txt\" \"C:\temp\0001NYoutput-short1.mov\"" };
    // print the command to execute
    for (String x : commandStr) {
        System.out.print(x + " ");
    }

    // execute ffmpeg with the command generated by the previous segment
    try {
        ProcessBuilder proc =  new ProcessBuilder(commandStr);
        proc.directory(new File("C:\temp"));
        //proc.command(commandStr);
        proc.start();

    } catch (IOException ex) {          
        ex.getMessage();
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

the error is

```
    The system cannot find the file specified
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(Unknown Source)
    at com.xuggle.xuggler.demos.FfmpegCommandTest.main(FfmpegCommandTest.java:21)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.create(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(Unknown Source)
```

Answer (score 1):

for the command stuff: use `\"C:\\temp\\0001NY.MXF\"` instead of \"C:\temp\0001NY.MXF\".

See double back-slash.